# getting Exception java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong format: RAW bytes needed

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa, public-key-encryption

Im trying to write a program for encrypting, signing and decrypting files using private public keys .  While running the program below i receive the following error -

> Exception in thread "main"  `java.security.InvalidKeyException`: Wrong format: RAW bytes needed at `com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.getKeyBytes(CipherCore.java:623)` at `com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:494)` at `com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:458)` at `com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:307)` at `javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1226)` at
>   `javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1166)` at
>   `Main.main(Main.java:87)`

## MY CODE

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Main
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, CertificateException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, SignatureException{
        //open the file containing keys
        File file = new File("keys/ks_file.jks");
        //cipher object that will hold the information
        Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        //create keystore object from stored keys inside the file
        KeyStore keystore = loadKeyStore(file, "sergey", "JKS");
        //messageDigest instance
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        //singanture instance
        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA"); 

        //params for getting keys
        String allias = "enc_key", password = "sergey";
        SecureRandom s_random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        //create random bytes for semtric key
        byte key_bytes[] = new byte[16];
        s_random.setSeed(711);
        s_random.nextBytes(key_bytes);

        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(key_bytes, "AES");

        Key key_enc = keystore.getKey(allias, password.toCharArray());
        KeyPair enc_key = null;

        if (key_enc instanceof PrivateKey) {
            // Get certificate of public key
            java.security.cert.Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(allias);
            // Get public key
            PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
            enc_key = new KeyPair(publicKey, (PrivateKey) key_enc);
        }
        //cipher the file
        aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        FileInputStream fis; 
        FileOutputStream fos; 
        CipherInputStream cis; 
        fis = new FileInputStream("tmp/a.txt"); 
        cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, aes);
        fos = new FileOutputStream("tmp/b.txt"); 
        byte[] b = new byte[8]; 
        int i = cis.read(b); 
        byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(i).array();
        //update message digest for signature
        md.update(bytes);
        while (i != -1) { 
            fos.write(b, 0, i); 
            i = cis.read(b);
            bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(i).array();
            md.update(bytes);
        } 
        fis.close();
        cis.close();
        fos.close();

        //encode the secret key
        /****************   ERROR HAPPENS IN NEXT LINE - LINE 87    *******************/
        aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (Key)enc_key.getPublic());
        byte[] cipherKey = aes.doFinal(key.toString().getBytes());

        //we save the final digest
        byte[] hash = md.digest();
        //init singature with private key
        dsa.initSign(enc_key.getPrivate());
        //update the signature with the hash aster digest
        dsa.update(hash); 
        //final signature
        byte[] sig = dsa.sign();

        //creating config xml
        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            // root elements
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("config");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            // signature elements
            Element sig_xml = doc.createElement("sig");
            rootElement.appendChild(sig_xml);
            sig_xml.setAttribute("value", sig.toString());

            // key element
            Element key_xml = doc.createElement("key");
            rootElement.appendChild(key_xml);
            key_xml.setAttribute("value", cipherKey.toString());

            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("./config.xml"));

            transformer.transform(source, result);

            System.out.println("File saved!");

          } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
          } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

    /**
     * Reads a Java keystore from a file.
     * 
     * @param keystoreFile
     *          keystore file to read
     * @param password
     *          password for the keystore file
     * @param keyStoreType
     *          type of keystore, e.g., JKS or PKCS12
     * @return the keystore object
     * @throws KeyStoreException
     *           if the type of KeyStore could not be created
     * @throws IOException
     *           if the keystore could not be loaded
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     *           if the algorithm used to check the integrity of the keystore
     *           cannot be found
     * @throws CertificateException
     *           if any of the certificates in the keystore could not be loaded
     */
    public static KeyStore loadKeyStore(final File keystoreFile,
        final String password, final String keyStoreType)
        throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        CertificateException {
      if (null == keystoreFile) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Keystore url may not be null");
      }
      final URI keystoreUri = keystoreFile.toURI();
      final URL keystoreUrl = keystoreUri.toURL();
      final KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
      InputStream is = null;
      try {
        is = keystoreUrl.openStream();
        keystore.load(is, null == password ? null : password.toCharArray());
      } finally {
        if (null != is) {
          is.close();
        }
      }
      return keystore;
    }

}
```

The specific line, in which the exception occurs is:

```
aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (Key)enc_key.getPublic());
```

Comment: The stack trace explicitly mentions the line, in which the exception occurs. Please point out which line in your code this is as the snippet you posted is somewhat longish.

Comment: Hi, sorry for that .. i marked it in the code                      .  the line is                               aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, (Key)enc_key.getPublic());

Comment: Next time, please provide a reason for downvote.

Comment: @user2993422. No, you did not.  It is to remind other users of this site to think before they click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AES is a symmetric cipher algorithm, for this it needs a symmetric key, not a public key.

In order to create symmetric key, use helper class [SecretKeySpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html).

Your encryption scheme should create a random sequence of bits as a key material for AES cipher, and then encrypt/decrypt this key material with Public/Private keys.

The message itself should be encrypted/decrypted with AES key.

Comment: hi, i don't fully understand.. i made a symmetric key with secretKey Spec in the folowing line -  Key key = new SecretKeySpec(key_bytes, "AES"); should i change the line with the error to -  aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);   the program runs if I do that , but i really don't know if it is ok or not.. thanks for the help :)

Comment: @user2993422. Yes, this is the way to use a symmetric cipher key.  If you want to protect that symmetric key, you can now encrypt it with your public key, and decrypt with your private key.